# Incompatible block pointer types sending 'id issue with ViperMcFlurry

Tags: swift, objective-c, ios14, viper-architecture, xcode12beta6

I was using ViperMcFlurry in my project without a problem for years and with XCode 12 beta 6 it returns me in `Incompatible block pointer types sending` error. I have tried various ways to fix it but no chance. It returns

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'id<RamblerViperModuleOutput> (^)(__strong id<RamblerModuleBetaInput>)' to parameter of type 'RamblerViperModuleLinkBlock' (aka 'id<RamblerViperModuleOutput> (^)(__strong id<RamblerViperModuleInput>)')
```

What I try to do is

```
[[self.transitionHandler openModuleUsingSegue:RamblerAlphaToBetaSegue]
 thenChainUsingBlock:^id<RamblerViperModuleOutput>(id<RamblerModuleBetaInput> moduleInput) {
     [moduleInput configureWithExampleString:exampleString];
     return nil;
 }];
```

and I have

```
@protocol RamblerModuleBetaInput <RamblerViperModuleInput>
```

in `RamblerModuleBetaInput.h`. Also I have

```
@protocol RamblerViperModuleInput <NSObject>
```

in `RamblerViperModuleInput.h`

Comment: From the error - it wants ```RamblerViperModuleInput``` and you are passing in ```RamblerViperModuleBetaInput``` ... spot the difference - hint is beta ...

Comment: Yes but then I cannot call moduleInput configureWithExampleString:exampleString.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/ViperMcFlurry/pull/37 or temporarily you can work it around by adding flags into Build Settings `CFLAGS` to disable check `-Xclang -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking`.